# Where are the settings of xcache?

Tags: php.ini

I'm on Dreamhost PS, using their preset xcache. I need to increase the size of the var memory but can't find the definitions for xcache. Its not in the php.ini file. I searched for *xcache* files and couldn't find something that looks like xcache settings.

How can I find the right file on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it at the regular /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini file. I looked at the wrong place.

Comment: In the future, use either phpinfo() in a script, or php -v to confirm which php.ini it's actually reading from.  Sometimes there are a few php.ini's scattered throughout a system, seemingly just to annoy you.

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu 13.04 it is under /etc/php4/conf.d/20-xcache.ini

The 20- was added recently. It was not present in version 12.04.